# continue cannot be used outside of a loop

Tags: java

I get the error message "continue cannot be used outside of a loop" but it is inside a loop i think?

```
public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (isItOK == true);{
                //perform canvas drawing
                if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
                    continue;
                }
                Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
                c.drawARGB(255, 150, 150, 10);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```

Comment: Why [the redundancy](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/12807/make-a-big-deal-out-of-true)... sighs. `while (isItOK) {`

Comment: semicolons have meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the cause of your error:

```
  while (isItOK == true);{
```

remove `;` before `{`

Answer (score 1):

When you put a semicolon after a while loop statement, for example in your code:

```
while (isItOK == true);
```

It says to not do anything until that statement is no longer true. Therefore, your code will not commence until isItOK == false.

Simply put, by adding the semicolon you already closed your while loop, so "continue" is considered to be outside of it.

Remove the semicolon and it should work.

EDIT: My apologies, marcin_j, apparently I missed that you had already answered this question.